# Query Element Class on Directive Angular 2

Tags: class, angular

I am new to Angular 2 and I want to write a attribute directive that query the element searching for 'class1' class, if it is found then it should replace 'class1' with 'class2'.

Should look like this:

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, Renderer, Input} from 'angular2/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[my-directive]'
})
export class MyDirective {
  constructor(el: ElementRef, renderer: Renderer) {
    //Pseudo-code
    if (el.containsClass('class1')) {
      el.removeClass('class1');
      el.addClass('class2');
    } 
  }
}
```

Cant find any related documentation, so decided to write this question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your best option would be writing a directive that queries for `.class1`. Then `host` class `class2` and then using `Renderer` remove the original class. Here's an example

```
@Directive({
  selector : '.class1',
  host : {
    'class' : 'class2' // The element will host 'class2'
  }
})
class MyDirective {
  constructor(renderer: Renderer, elementRef: ElementRef) {

    // The third argument is false which will remove the class
    renderer.setElementClass(elementRef.nativeElement, 'class1', false);
  }
}
```

**Update**

This can be even simpler by evaluating `class1` to null. This way we can get rid of Renderer and ElementRef.

```
@Directive({
  selector : '.class1',
  host : {
    '[class.class2]' : 'true', // Set to 'true' to add the class
    '[class.class1]' : 'null'  // Set to 'null' to remove the class
  }
})
class MyDirective {}
```

**Note** Evaluating a class/attribute/property to null removes it.

Here's a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/VR4QluKPlz8vTa8jPn9k?p=preview) with the example working.

Comment: Can you explain in more details why are you hosting the class?

Comment: It's just a way of doing it. Personally I rather to use the component to do these kind of things. You could add it with Renderer as well.

Comment: @MarcosJ.CKichel I've updated my answer with a simpler form of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[test]',
  export class MytDirective {
    constructor(el: ElementRef, renderer: Renderer) {
      var classNameStr = el.nativeElement.className;
      if (/someclass/.test(classNameStr)) {
        renderer.setElementClass(el.nativeElement, 'someclass', false);
        renderer.setElementClass(el.nativeElement, 'otherclass', true);
      }
    }
  }
})
```

In fact, the `nativeElement` attribute corresponds to the DOM element the directive applies on. See this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.

The API for the `Renderer` class is described here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/Renderer-class.html.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry